# How to open a startup file in view-mode?

Tags: org-mode, start-up, view-mode

I configured Emacs (28.1) to open an index file (`index.org`) at startup. Now I would like this file to be opened in `view-mode`. I tried

```el
(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/PATH/index.org")
(view-mode t)
```

but `index.org` doesn't open in `view-mode`. How could I achieve this?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn `view-mode` on in the buffer of `index.org`. What you are doing is turning it on in whatever buffer is current when the `view-mode` call is evaluated. Try

```el
(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/PATH/index.org")
(with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "~/PATH/index.org")
   (view-mode t))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't comfortable with `emacs-lisp`, you can add the following three lines to the very bottom of your `~/PATH/index.org`, and save it.  Next time when you open that file in `Emacs`, it will be `read-only`.

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (view-mode 1)
# End:
```

If you don't want to close `Emacs`, you can try re-visiting the file in same session with `M-x revert-buffer RET`.  Now try editing the file, and see what happens.

The above suggestion will work only for `org` files.

---

You can add the above 3 lines with

1. `M-x add-file-local-variable <return> eval <return> ( view-mode SPC 1) <return>`
2. `C-x C-s`
3. `C-x C-v <return>`

This will add the 3 lines that I suggested previously.  Remember to save the file.

Above 3 steps will work for ***any*** file.